Mean Preserving Spreads as a Markov Kernel
From Blackwell's theorem, it is possible to draw an equivalence between one signal being a garbling of another and the statistical notion of a Mean Preserving Spread.
Consequently, at least in the context of Blackwell's Theorem, the following is an alternative definition of a MPS:
For a pair of distributions $F$ and $F'$ induced by two signals $\sigma' : \Theta \to \Delta(S')$ and $\sigma : \Theta \to \Delta(S')$, $F$ is Mean Preserving Spread of $F'$ if there exists a Markov Kernel $\gamma : S \to \Delta(S')$ such that:
$$\sigma'(s' | \theta) = \int_{s \in S} \gamma(s' |s) \sigma(s | \theta) ds$$
I know this is true due to the theorem, but I'm trying to prove the result directly, using the following (standard) definition of a Mean Preserving Spread:
For a pair of random variables from the pair of distributions $Z \sim F$ and $\tilde{Z} \sim \tilde{F}$, $F$ is a MPS of $\tilde{F}$ if:
$$\mathbb{E}(Z | \tilde{Z}) = \tilde{Z}$$
I have made the following partial attempt.
First, I note that in general:
$$\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = \int_A \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
Where $A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$.
In this case, I think (though am far from sure) that:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \gamma(s' |s) \sigma(s|\theta)$$
$$f_Y(y) = \gamma(s|s')$$
Consequently:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Z|\tilde{Z}) &= \int_{s' \in S'} \dfrac{\sigma'(s'|\theta)}{\gamma(s|s')} .ds'\\
&= \int_{s' \in S'} \dfrac{\sigma(s|\theta) \gamma(s|s')}{\gamma(s|s')} .ds' \\
&= \sigma(s|\theta)
\end{align}$$
Would someone be able to confirm that I've specified the densities correctly here, and if I have not, suggest what they should be?

The notation $\int_A$ for $A$ a $\sigma$-algebra is rarher unusual. More importantly, where do the densities come from?

@matthewoulton Are the notes in your link from some book? Are these some personal notes? They seem to be nice written and if it was some book I would like to read it more thouroughly. Recently, I became much interested in Blackwell theory about informational experiments and I see this is used so mych in Bayesian persuasion that is a field I find it challenging to understand. Could you please give me some information on the topic about your link?
Thank you in advance!

They're my own notes, but based on Annie Liang's, which you can find here:
https://www.anniehliang.com/lecture-notes
I think he notes are really well written and would highly recommend.
